# How to calculate the first and the last date of the week on the basis of week number?

Tags: php, mysql

How to calculate the first and the last date of the week on the basis of week number

Comment: What you had tried for same?

Comment: What is the first day of the week for you?

Comment: Sorry didn't get it?

Comment: Some regard Sunday as first day of week , some Monday and I have seen some with Friday.

Comment: What "some regard", and what is officially used are two different things. PHP treats Monday as the first day of the week, see [this live example](https://3v4l.org/bNaRD). If you're using a different standard, you can easily modify it by simply subtracting a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP DateTime class, with the help of `DateTime::setISODate` you can specify a year and week, and create a date from that. Then you can add six days to get the last day of the week.

```
$year = 2017;
$week = 10;

$date      = new DateTime();
$first_day = $date->setISODate($year, $week)->format('F jS, Y');
$last_day  = $date->modify('+6 days')->format('F jS, Y');

echo $first_day."\n";   // March 6th, 2017
echo $last_day;         // March 12th, 2017
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/mDiqh)

## References

- http://php.net/datetime.setisodate

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this: to identify the date of the Monday and Friday given a week?

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201701 Monday','%X%V %W'); 
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201701 Friday','%X%V %W');
```